# Can not "read" anything through the FUSE file system

Tags: c++, filesystems, fuse

I use fuse to build my own file system in MIT 6.824 lab, and the **read** operation is implemented in this function.

```
void
fuseserver_read(fuse_req_t req, fuse_ino_t ino, size_t size,
        off_t off, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    std::string buf;
    int r;
    if ((r = yfs->read(ino, size, off, buf)) == yfs_client::OK) {

        char* retbuf = (char *)malloc(buf.size());
        memcpy(retbuf,buf.data(),buf.size());
        //Print the information of the result.
        printf("debug read in fuse: the content of %lu is %s, size %lu\n",ino,retbuf, buf.size());

       fuse_reply_buf(req,retbuf,buf.size());    
    } else {
        fuse_reply_err(req, ENOENT);
    }

//global definition
//struct fuse_lowlevel_ops fuseserver_oper;

//In main()
//    fuseserver_oper.read       = fuseserver_read;
```

I print the information of the buf before it return.

The **write** operation is also implemented, of course.

Then I run a simple test to read out some words.

```
//test.c
int main(){
    //./yfs1 is the mount point of my filesystem
    int fd = open("./yfs1/test-file",O_RDWR | O_CREAT,0777);
    char* buf = "123";
    char* readout;
    readout = (char *)malloc(3);
    int writesize = write(fd,buf,3);
    int readsize = read(fd,readout,3);
    printf("%s,%d\n",buf,writesize);
    printf("%s,%d\n",readout,readsize);
    close(fd);
}
```

I can get nothing by read(fd,readout,3), but the information printed by the `fuseserver_read` shows that the buffer is read out successfully before `fuse_reply_buf`

```sh
$ ./test
123,3
,0
```

```
debug read in fuse: the content of 2 is 123, size 3
```

So why the `read()` in test.c can not read anything from my file system??

Comment: is the return value of `fuse_reply_buf` 0?

Comment: @Botje Yeah, the fuse_reply_buf returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I've made a mistake to write my test file. The file pointer will point to the end of the file after "write" and of course can read nothing later. So simply reopen the file can make the test work.
Secondly, before read() operation of FUSE, the FUSE will getattr() first and truncate the result of the read() operation with the "size" attribute of the file. So it must be very careful to manipulate the attribute of a file.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a need to notify that you have finished reading by sending an empty buffer, as an "EOF". You can do that by using `reply_buf_limited`.
Take a look at `hello_ll` example in the [*fuse* source tree](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/hello_ll.c#L147):

```java
static void tfs_read(fuse_req_t req, fuse_ino_t ino, size_t size,
                     off_t off, struct fuse_file_info *fi) {
    (void) fi;

    assert(ino == FILE_INO);
    reply_buf_limited(req, file_contents, file_size, off, size);
}

static int reply_buf_limited(fuse_req_t req, const char *buf, size_t bufsize,
                 off_t off, size_t maxsize)
{
    if (off < bufsize)
        return fuse_reply_buf(req, buf + off,
                      min(bufsize - off, maxsize));
    else
        return fuse_reply_buf(req, NULL, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work by replacing the `fuse_reply_buf()` to `reply_buf_limited()`. Why the `reply_buf_limited()` can help to notify the end of reading?

Comment: It notifies the end of reading by returning a null buffer after all data was copied. Please mount fuse with the `debug` option to get log messages in stdout for every operation.